# How do I seperate 2 outputs from each other in python

Tags: python, process

```
gate = input("Choose\nA) for 'AND' gate and\nB) for 'OR' gate\n")

if gate == "A":
    val1 = float(input("Whats your A value?"))
    val2 = float(input("Whats your B value?"))

if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
    print("Your C value is 0")

if val1 == 0 and val2 == 1:
    print("Your C value is 0")

if val1 == 1 and val2 == 0:
    print("Your C value is 0")

if val1 == 1 and val2 == 1:
    print("Your C value is 1")

#Right here is the error, I need something to separate top process from bottom process

if gate == "B":
    val1 = float(input("Whats your A value?"))
    val2 = float(input("Whats your B value?"))

if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
    print("Your C value is 0")

if val1 == 0 and val2 == 1:
    print("Your C value is 1")

if val1 == 1 and val2 == 1:
    print("Your C value is 1")

if val1 == 1 and val2 == 0:
    print("Your C value is 1")
```

So everything works, If I just put the `if gate == "A":` section and not the `if gate == "B":` part it work. From my experience in C, I feel like I need something that seperates both tasks / processes from each other, may someone tell me the line of code, I've searched many places on the internet and still haven't found a solution.

Comment: What kind of "separation" are you looking for?  Do you want all the other `if`s to be inside the `gate ==` checks?  If so, just indent them to be part of the correct block

Comment: I want if gate A separated from if gate B, so they are TWO totally different processes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate the two processes, this is probably what you want to do:

```
def process_A():
    val1 = int(input("Whats your A value?"))
    val2 = int(input("Whats your B value?"))

    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
        print("Your C value is 0")

    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 1:
        print("Your C value is 0")

    if val1 == 1 and val2 == 0:
        print("Your C value is 0")

    if val1 == 1 and val2 == 1:
        print("Your C value is 1")

def process_B():
    val1 = int(input("Whats your A value?"))
    val2 = int(input("Whats your B value?"))

    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
        print("Your C value is 0")

    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 1:
        print("Your C value is 1")

    if val1 == 1 and val2 == 1:
        print("Your C value is 1")

    if val1 == 1 and val2 == 0:
        print("Your C value is 1")


gate = input("Choose\nA) for 'AND' gate and\nB) for 'OR' gate\n")

if gate == "A":
    process_A()
elif gate == "B":
    process_B()
```

### output:

**Input A --> A process:**

```
Choose
A) for 'AND' gate and
B) for 'OR' gate
B
Whats your A value?0
Whats your B value?0
Your C value is 0
```

**Input A --> A process:**

```
Choose
A) for 'AND' gate and
B) for 'OR' gate
A
Whats your A value?1
Whats your B value?1
Your C value is 1
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same error, when I type A In console, it works, but B doesn't. I get this error. 

 if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
NameError: name 'val1' is not defined

And that error refers to line 7 on your version, and also

When I type A it works, but lets say I put the values 1 and 1, it gives me the output "Your C value is 1" twice, because it goes through both processes, I still need to find how I can "break" the process.

Comment: It works for me, this is strange... I changed the casting into `floats` to a casting into `int` to prevent float imprecision to fool the `==`. Would you like to try again?

Comment: I refactored each process in a separate function. Does it work on your side now?

Comment: It still doesn't work, if you tried the code, would you mind sharing what yours looks like?

Replying to your comment "It works for me..."


Your updated version works!! thanks so much

Comment: Added output for A abd B processes

Answer (score 0):

```
gate = raw_input("Choose\nA) for 'AND' gate and\nB) for 'OR' gate\n")

if gate == "A":
    val1 = input("Whats your A value?")
    val2 = input("Whats your B value?")

    if val1 == 1 and val2 == 1:
        print("Your C value is 1")
    else:
        print("Your C value is 0")


#Right here is the error, I need something to separate top process from bottom process

if gate == "B":
    val1 = input("Whats your A value?")
    val2 = input("Whats your B value?")
    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
        print("Your C value is 0")
    else:
        print("Your C value is 1")
```

I changed the input for raw_input for get the letter like string, and I compressed the code because no need more validation when have the same response.